# Heroku rollback when running rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I have been looking for a while a solution to this, I have found some like put the version of ruby in your gemfile so as not to run into the rollback error when seeding, etc. However, nothing worked. This is my third app I'm deploying to Heroku and the first time I'm running into the following error:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "b@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 1], ["email", "b@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$K.dh0OhopIOVZgT..0Yi7ukDGcw/IHmCAmZaH7LuHWZnfbJLaSWzS"], ["created_at", 2017-01-05 17:07:23 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-05 17:07:23 UTC], ["username", "paco"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Where I have a username with a 654321 password as an example that is being  encrypted as you see on the second to last line.

This is my schema:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161231124005) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "bids", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_bids_on_product_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bids_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "bids", "products"
  add_foreign_key "bids", "users"
end
```

These are my seeds where I'm trying to give a random usernames (because I added that column to devise gem):

```html
category1 = Category.create(name: "computers")
category2 = Category.create(name: "mobile")
category3 = Category.create(name: "clothes")
category4 = Category.create(name: "accesories")

Product.create(category: category1, title: "McBook", description: "Best PC for developers", price: 500,image_url: "mc-book.jpg", user_id: 1, deadline: "12/11/2016")
Product.create(category: category3,title: "Winter jacket", description: "Keep it warm even in wintertime", price: 40,image_url: "winter-jacket.png", user_id: 1, deadline: "18/04/2016")
Product.create(category: category4,title: "Rayban sunglasses", description: "Cool sunglasses for summertime", price: 60,image_url: "rayban.jpg", user_id: 1, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category3,title: "Casual Jacket", description: "Cool jacket", price: 20,image_url: "jacket.jpg", user_id: 1, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category1,title: "HP computer", description: "Ultimate computer", price: 300,image_url: "hp.png", user_id: 1, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category4,title: "Normal sunglasses", description: "Geeky glasses", price: 10,image_url: "sunglasses.png", user_id: 1, deadline: "09/12/2016")

10.times do |index|
  User.create(username: "user-#{ SecureRandom.hex(10)}", email: "email#{index}@example.com", password: 'password123#')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the user with same email `("b@gmail.com")` already exist in database and I think you have uniqueness validation on `email`

```
User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "b@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Change the email for users using sequence something like this

```
10.times do |index|
  User.create(email: "email#{index}@example.com", password: 'password123#')
end
```

This will create 10 users with different emails

```
email0@example.com
email1@example.com
email2@example.com
email3@example.com
email4@example.com
email5@example.com
email6@example.com
email7@example.com
email8@example.com
email9@example.com
```

Comment: Nops I run into the same error "rollback". My app is running ok in localhost but when I'm deploying I find that error when heroku run rake db:seed

Comment: If I run rake db:seed without heroku I get the following:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"

However, I don't get why I get the "encrypted_password" there...

Answer (score 0):

I did it. I typed the following in models:

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :products
 has_many :ratings
 has_many :bids
 validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i },
    uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Then and this I don't know why the relationship between the user_id from and the products when I moved to Postgres was giving me errors so I did it with: rails g migration AddUserToProducts user:references.

Then drop the database in production with: heroku pg:reset DATABASE

Changing the seeds for the following:

```html
category1 = Category.create(name: "computers")
category2 = Category.create(name: "mobile")
category3 = Category.create(name: "clothes")
category4 = Category.create(name: "accesories")

Product.create(category: category1, title: "McBook", description: "Best PC for developers", price: 500,image_url: "mc-book.jpg", user_id: 2, deadline: "12/11/2016")
Product.create(category: category3,title: "Winter jacket", description: "Keep it warm even in wintertime", price: 40,image_url: "winter-jacket.png", user_id: 2, deadline: "18/04/2016")
Product.create(category: category4,title: "Rayban sunglasses", description: "Cool sunglasses for summertime", price: 60,image_url: "rayban.jpg", user_id: 2, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category3,title: "Casual Jacket", description: "Cool jacket", price: 20,image_url: "jacket.jpg", user_id: 2, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category1,title: "HP computer", description: "Ultimate computer", price: 300,image_url: "hp.png", user_id: 2, deadline: "09/12/2016")
Product.create(category: category4,title: "Normal sunglasses", description: "Geeky glasses", price: 10,image_url: "sunglasses.png", user_id: 2, deadline: "09/12/2016")

User.create(id: 2, email: "b@gmail.com", username: "paco", password: "653412")
```

And finally running heroku run rake db:migrate and heroku run rake db:seed.

This time the products are being saved although the user log in form the user in seeds doesn't work. So I sign up another user (in the front-end) and assigned the products to him.